# Как передать текст из переменной в массив

Tags: php

Есть переменная

```
$a='1,2,3,4,5';
```

Как из нее передать 1,2,3,4,5 в массив, чтобы получился подобный массив

```
$array = array('1','2','3','4','5');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)
Она разбивает строку на части по некоторому статичному разделителю:

```
$a = '1,2,3,4,5';
$array = explode(',', $a);
```

Для более сложных случаев есть функция [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php)
Она позволяет в качестве разделителя использовать регулярное выражение:

```
$a = '1,2;3, 4, 5';
$array = preg_split('[,;]\s*', $a);
```

---

Для осуществления обратной операции (склейка строки из массива) существует функция [implode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

```
$a = implode(', ', $array); // '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'
```